# Using Oracle MEMBER OF operator with VARRAY columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

Consider the following script:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t1 AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
/
CREATE TYPE t2 AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(10);
/

CREATE TABLE t (
  id NUMBER(10),
  t1 t1,
  t2 t2
)
NESTED TABLE t1 STORE AS t1_nt;

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, t1('abc'), t2('abc'));

SELECT * FROM t WHERE 'abc' MEMBER OF t1;
SELECT * FROM t WHERE 'abc' MEMBER OF t2;
```

The output of the last two `SELECT` statements is

```
ID    T1      T2
-------------------
2     [abc]   [abc]

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got 
SQL_XQMZQAMSETXZLGIEEEEBUTFWF.T2
```

[The documentation claims that this operation should be possible for varrays as well as for nested tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52138):

> A member_condition is a membership condition that tests whether an element is a member of a nested table. The return value is TRUE if expr is equal to a member of the specified nested table or varray.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that must be a documentation bug. It says 'nested table' in five places, but only mentions 'varray' in that second sentence, *'The return value is TRUE if expr is equal to a member of the specified nested table or varray.'* The same text appears in the 18c documentation so perhaps someone should tell them.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: Yep, definitely a documentation bug: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:12:0::NO::P12_ORIG,P12_PREV_PAGE,P12_QUESTION_ID:Y,1,9538544100346396908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a documentation bug, see this [AskTom question and answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:12:0::NO::P12_ORIG,P12_PREV_PAGE,P12_QUESTION_ID:Y,1,9538544100346396908).

A workaround is to run this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE(t2) WHERE column_value = 'abc'
)
```

[I've written up a blog post showing emulations of all the multiset conditions and operators](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/08/15/how-to-write-multiset-conditions-with-oracle-varray-types/), in case someone else finds this useful.